# Why Visual Studio intellisense doesn't show XMLHttpRequest objects methods?

Tags: javascript, ajax, visual-studio-2010

I am trying access XMLHttpRequest() object's open and send methods but i can't see them in intellisense of Visual Studio but why ?

```
var httprequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httprequest.
```

can't see methods by intellisense after dot.

Answer (score 0):

If your Javascript code does not 'compile' i.e. incomplete braces or syntax errors then the intellisense will not 'understand' your object.  Try creating a new js file and only include the lines you quoted and you should get the 7 standard object options in intellisense.

You will not get open and send methods shown, just the 'constructor', 'hasOwnProperty', 'toString' etc.